# Printing connected users in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear 

echo "The script starts now."
echo "Hi, user!"
echo 

echo "I will now fetch you a list of connected users:"
echo 
w

echo "I'm setting two variables now."
COLOUR="black"
VALUE="9"

echo "This is a string: $COLOUR"
echo "And this is a number: $VALUE"
echo
```

I observed that the effect of w is that it prints the following:

```
 18:06:36 up  7:43,  3 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.56, 0.64
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
hes      tty7                      10:23    7:43m 12:31   0.96s gnome-session -
hes      pts/0    :0               15:41    4.00s  1.38s 11.46s gnome-terminal
hes       pts/2    :0               17:20   44:52   0.79s 11.46s gnome-terminal
```

when I typed echo " statement" in terminal , it prints the statement. But I could not understand w here. in terminal echo w , prints w not as above.
Can someone help me in understanding how this work?

Comment: Please see `man w`

Comment: Oh, I did not know this one character command!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note: there is no difference between a "string" and a "number" in bash. Even `declare -i` does not change type, it just artificially adds limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you're doing. `w` is a command and your scriptis running it, what were you expecting?

```
## This echo prints the string within the quotes: "I will ..."
echo "I will now fetch you a list of connected users:"
## This echo prints an empty line
echo 
## This runs the command 'w' which prints connected users
w
```

`echo w` on the other hand will simply print the letter `w` since you are not running the command. If you want to `echo` the command's output, run `echo $(w)`. That, however, is pointless since it will loose the formatting and simply running `w` is enough.